# Explanation about the CS Ph.D. programs in Canada

Tags: phd, computer-science, canada

Could somebody explain how CS Ph.D. programs are structured in Canada, is there courses to sit for ? if yes, how many. Also what's the typical duration to complete one and what's the possible funding opportunities sources ? are they always depending on the supervisor ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Canada, there are some PhD programs with courses and some without courses. The numbers of courses can vary. It could be 0, 2，5 or more, for example. In some program, you can do the courses in one or two semesters while for other programs it can be more. The length of the PhD program is usually at least 3 years in CS. I have seen some programs where it was at least 4 years and half (e.g. for my PhD). And if you do the PhD part-time, you may have to add a few more years.
And all of this depends on the university and the research area. But in any case, the real length of a PhD depends on your research progress. I have seen some people finishing the PhD after 10 years due to some slow research progress and doing it part-time!

As for funding, the supervisor may pay you some money, the department or university may have some money for students, you may get some jobs like teaching some course or being a TA, and some province also have scholarships (depends on the province) and the national government may also have some scholarships. But some scholarships are only for Canadians or permanent residents so some international students may not receive them. Also, there are some government programs to support those doing a PhD with the industry (such as MITACS). Generally, to find funding, the first step is to talk with your potential supervisor to see if he has some funding and to read the university website to see if they suggest some funding sources.  Some university have some online calculator to let you estimate the cost of life for your studies so you can do some planning.

Also, you need to know that Canada has several provinces and unviersities in different provinces follow some different systems, and the cost for the PhD program can be quite different from one province to another (e.g. universities in Quebec follow a slightly different system from Ontario, and the tuition fees are quite different).

Comment: Are you saying that funding is usually partly and that many fundings should cover the fees and life costs while a PhD student ? Also is there PhD programs with 0 courses to sit for ? also in Quebec it is cheaper than Ontario or the opposite ?

Comment: Many supervisors dont have enough funding to fully pay a PhD student.  If you have a chance to do a PhD as part of an industrial project, you can be well paid, or maybe if you work for some famous professor. If you are permanent resident/canadian, the government has some good scholarships too for those among the best. Otherwise, you may combine different sources of funding such as getting a few thousands dollars from the supervisors, teaching some course, getting some scholarship from university maybe etc.

Comment: To my knowledge, Quebec is in general cheaper than Ontario for tuituion fee. But it depends on your status.  If you live in Quebec for at least 2 years (or something like that - cannot remember) and are a permanent resident/Canadian or you have French citizenship, you get very low tuition fee (e.g. as a Quebecer paid maybe 1000$ or less per semester, while in Ontario i would have paid at least double if i remember). But if you are an international student, the story is different. The tuition fee could be much higher.

Comment: Yes, I think you should be able to find PhD programs with zero course, or otherwise they may have 1 or 2.  That should be the normal case (0-2).

Comment: By the way, i forgot to mention in my answer that some provinces do have a "loan and bursury" program. That means that under some conditions like being a permanent resident or Canadian, the governement can  lend some money to students that they can pay back later after the PhD. This is what some students are using also to get some money for their university education (from my experience in Quebec).

Comment: Lets take the case where i am an international student who happen to complete a 2 years master's and got a permanent resident status, in Quebec how much do i have to pay per year in the PhD program ?

Comment: It depends on the university. So if we take McGill University as example (an English speaking University), there is a calculator: https://www.mcgill.ca/student-accounts/tuition-charges/fallwinter-term-tuition-and-fees/graduate-fees. A resident of Quebec would pay 2000-2600 $ CAD/ semester, while an international around 8000-10,000 CAD$. Two semesters per year to be paid, so around 4600$ per year for a resident and 18k $ per year for an international PhD full time.

Comment: If you have status of resident of Quebec, then, I think you would pay the fee of around 4600$ / year  rather than the 18k $ per year for regular international students. But I just check this quickly for you. You may read the website of specific universities to get more details

Comment: By the way, province of Quebec has special rules.  To be considered resident of Quebec, you may have to stay there for a while, even if you are permanent resident of Canada (something to be verified - these rules are not clear to me)

Comment: ok thanks, but what about postdoc positions when someone has a phd from abroad ? are postdocs positions frequent in Ontario for example ?

Comment: There are some post-doc positions but not so many...  The problem is that a professor needs money to pay a postdoc and the government dont give much funding to researchers.  However, the government has a good supporting platform (MITACS) for doing a post-doc in colalboration with a company (not so hard to get it). And if you are a permanent resident and want to do a post-doc you can apply for scholarships of provincial or national government. If you have a good profile, you may get it. For example, as a Canadian, I got a scholarship that fully paid my postdoc that I did outside Canada.

Comment: The important is work hard during your PhD, try to get some good papers, get collaboration and get to know the people... It may help you to find some post-doc opportunity. And if you have a good profile, you may be successful with postdoc scholarships.  Generally, people may be interested to hire you for the post-doc if you have shown that you are good at research during your PhD.

Comment: If you want to see some examples of job posting for post-docs you can search through this website:  https://www.universityaffairs.ca/search-job/  which is the main website to look for academic jobs.  Some post-doc positions will clearly mention that Canadians and permanent residents have priority when applying for some post-doc position. For example: "All qualified candidates are encouraged to apply; however, Canadian citizens and permanent residents are given priority. Canadians and permanent residents should indicate their citizenship status in their application.".

Comment: Alright, and does a foreign PhD qualify for assistant professors positions ?

Comment: A PhD is enough for applying for an assistant professor position or lecturer position. The PhD can be foreign or it can be obtained in Canada. That does not make much difference.  However, what can make a difference is if you are a permanent resident or Canadian citizen as some universities may give priority to permanent resident or citizen over other people.  This answer is for CS.  If you were in some other field like medicine, then maybe a PhD abroad would maybe not be reconigzed in Canada. But for CS, a foreign PhD is OK.